# Adding onClick function to select elements

Tags: javascript, select

I have a select tag of dynamically added elements. I need to add an event listener to each of the elements in the select tag except the first which:

adds the text of the element to a list,
makes the focus of the list the first element again, and
removes or hides the clicked element.

The first element is a 'none' element which doesn't need any event listener.

I've tried something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var name = array[i];
    var selectElement = document.getElementById(selectElementId);

    addToSelectNode(document.getElementById(selectElementId), name);

    var thisNode = selectElement.childNodes[i];

    if (thisNode.value != "none")
    {
        thisNode.addEventListener("click", function(event)
        {       
            appendNodeToList("artist-list", i);
            selectElement.selectedIndex = 0;
            selectElement.remove(selectElement.i);
            selectElement.style.display = "none";
        });
    }
}

function addToSelectNode(element, optionText)
{
    var newSelectElement = document.createElement("option");
    newSelectElement.text = optionText;
    element.add(newSelectElement);
}

function appendNodeToList(listId, text)
{
    var newNode = document.createElement("LI");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    newNode.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById(listId).appendChild(newNode);
}
```

Didn't work at all though

Comment: I'd recomment you using some framework, most probably VueJS, for that

Comment: please add [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with you codes and errors

Answer (score 0):

A few hours later I've solved my own question. The problem stemmed from trying to remove items in the select tag which just wasn't working - I'm nut sure if it's possible but making it disabled solved it. Anyway here's the result.

HTML:

```
<select id="artist-select-list">
            <option value="none">none</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("sampleDropdown");
    var n = array.length;

    // Loop to add to <select> dropdown
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        addToSelectNode(dropdown, array[i - 1]);
    }

    // Loop to add id's to each element in the dropdown
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        dropdown[i].id = "selectNum" + i;
    }

    // Loop to add event listener
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++)
    {
        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function(event)
        {
            // Regardless of which option the user clicks move shown option to "none" (first index in dropdown)
            dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

            if (event.target.id != "selectNum0")
            {
                // Disable once clicked
                event.target.disabled = true;

                // Do other things here in relation to event.target
            }
        });
    }
}

var array =
[
    "sampleText1", "sampleText2"
];

function addToSelectNode(element, optionText)
{
    var newSelectElement = document.createElement("option");
    newSelectElement.text = optionText;
    element.add(newSelectElement);
}
```